# How can I plot line graph with categorical and numeric (datum) axes?

Tags: python, seaborn

Seaborn enables you to create a categorical plot using points

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataste('tips')
sns.catplot(x='tip', y='sex', data=tips, jitter=False)
```

[image]

Is there a way to connect the points with a line for the same gender?

My goal is to create a plot that will be similar to the below figure (done in [R's ggplot2](http://rpubs.com/RomanL/347314)). Reading the [seaborn documentation](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn.catplot) I find nothing that would resemble this plot. The [lineplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html#seaborn.lineplot) only takes in numeric values. Is currently there an obvious way to make this categorical plot this that I'm missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the category and plot each line individually.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def cat_horizontal_plot(data, category, numeric, ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    for cat, num in data.groupby(category):
        ax.plot(np.sort(num[numeric].values), [cat]*len(num),
                marker="o", mec="k", mfc="none", linestyle="-", color="k")
    ax.set_xlabel(numeric)
    ax.set_ylabel(category)
    ax.margins(y=0.4)
    ax.figure.tight_layout()
```

Use it as

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

cat_horizontal_plot(tips, "sex", "tip")
plt.show()
```

[image]